# How to compile ocaml program with using Graphics module by ocamlopt?

Tags: graphics, compilation, ocaml, libraries, native-code

As I understand, graphics.cma**x** isn't exist.
But how to compile ocaml program with using Graphics module  by ocaml**opt**? 
Is it possible? Maybe some alternative graphics libraries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, graphics.cma**x** indeed doesn't exist, why it should? But graphics.cm**x**a does. So of course it is possible compile programs that use graphics library to a machine code. You can  use `ocamlfind` to find a proper library depending on your compilation mode. For example on mine machine:

```
$ ocamlfind query -predicates native -a-format graphics
  /home/ivg/.opam/fresh/lib/ocaml/graphics.cmxa
```

In a simple case, like this, with the graphics library that is distributed with the OCaml system itself, you can just add `graphics.cmxa` to the compilation string. On more complex cases, just use `ocamlfind ocamlopt` instead of `ocamlopt`, and specify `-package` option to refer to a library name, in your case it would be:

```
 $ ocamlfind ocamlopt -package graphics ...
```

Or you can use `ocamlbuld`:

```
 $ ocamlbuild -package graphics my_cool_application.native
```

where your cool application has an entry point in the `my_cool_application.ml` file.

Comment: So sorry for really stupid question with bold. Two days of continuous work.